# Network .bat with AD User credentials

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, active-directory

Morning all,

I am attempting to write a .bat to map a network drive when our users logon. I have the below which works:

```
@echo off
If Exist S:\ net use s: /delete
Net Use s: \\192.168.1.88\NASData /Persistent:Yes
```

This maps the drive without a problem. My question,  is how do I incorporate the users AD logon credentials please?

I'm aware of `/User:User password` but I want this to populate the individual users details from AD. Using our Admin account, adding the above line does work, but I'm hoping to be able to pull the users details from AD, rather than putting them in myself. Can this be done please?!

Cheers,

Comment: You cannot just put many commands one after the other on the same line like that and expect them to work! _(You are using a batch file, so there is no need to limit it to a single line)_. Also there's no such command as `enter`.

Comment: Hi Compo. Apologies, "Enter" was my typo. The above is the code you kindly helped with last week, so it does work. Is there a way I can take the user credentials from AD without manually inputting them please? As stated, the /User password does work, but I don't know how to get the batch to take the credentials from AD.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you are running it. Don't run it with admin credentials. You need to run the bat file under the user's credentials - so it needs to be a user logon script.

A user logon script is stored on the domain controllers and then set on the user's AD account, or in a group policy.

Here is a page that describes how to do this with setting the logon script on individual AD accounts: https://www.petri.com/setting-up-logon-script-through-active-directory-users-computers-windows-server-2008

Or by group policy: https://www.petri.com/setting-up-logon-script-through-gpo-windows-server-2008